# Printing an NSMutableArray causes crash with no error code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, nsmutablearray

I determined that my application crashes on the following line:

```
if(sourceValues != nil && [sourceValues class] == [NSMutableArray class])
    [sourceValues release];
```

"sourceValues" is declared as an NSMutableArray at the top of my class. The "if" loop is satisfied, and the [sourceValues release] call gets made, which crashes the program with no error code. So, since sourceValues != nil and since [sourceValues class] == [NSMutableArray class], I wanted to see exactly what sourceValues was. So, above the "if" loop I added the following:

```
NSLog(@"sourceValues is %@", sourceValues);
```

But my program will not print it. It just crashes with no error code on that line. So, if sourceValue exists and if it an NSMutableArray, why will it not be printed. What is the problem here?

I'm trying to have code that says "if sourceValues has been allocated, release it." How can I do this?

Comment: Also, how is `sourceValues` allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use:

```
if(sourceValues != nil && [sourceValues isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
    [sourceValues release];
```

You may want to use other methods like:

- `isMemberOfClass:`

Comment: If the problem still exist, it means the problem goes with the releasing of your object. You may want to show us the rest of the code.

Comment: No amount of testing of `sourceValues` is going to help if `sourceValues` is already released.

Answer (score 1):

If this...

```
NSLog(@"sourceValues is %@", sourceValues);
```

... is crashing your program, it is because `sourceValues` has already been released.  Wherever you `release` `sourceValues`, set it to `nil`.

```
[sourceValues release], sourceValues = nil;
```

If your app is still crashing, it is because the array has been over-released somewhere else. That is, you didn't correctly balance retains and releases.  First, try "build and analyze" and fix any problems the static analyzer identifies.   Next, turn on zombie detection and see where you are first messaging the over-released object.

Note that `[sourceValues class] == [NSMutableArray class]` will not work and that pattern should never be used to check if an instance is of a particular class.   You should always use `isKindOfClass:` or `isMemberOfClass:`.

However, since you can't tell the difference between a mutable or immutable array anyway, there is no point to checking in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, there's no danger in releasing a `nil` object. So the issue of "if sourceValues has been allocated, release it." is probably superfluous. Unless you're doing some funky stuff, you should follow regular memory management rules and just call `[sourceValues release];` in `dealloc`

Have you tried running everything with breakpoints on ("Build and Debug - Breakpoints On" in Xcode)? That usually gives you more debug information than the usual "Build and run".

It might be (I'm guessing based on some odd problems I've had in the past) that you've actually dealloced `sourceValues` already but the pointer is still pointing to its old memory. If that happens, a new object might be situated in that area which the program will attempt to treat like an NSMutableArray anyway.

Comment: but I'm not using dealloc. is there not a way to just say "if X has been allocated, release it"

Comment: You're not using dealloc? That sounds like you're doing something wrong... release never actually "frees" any memory; it's only responsible for lowering the retain count by 1. If the retain count reaches 0, then dealloc is called to free the memory.

Comment: Why not just release it? You can send release to nil with no adverse affects.

Comment: THere should never be a line of code that calls `dealloc` on an array.  If he doesn't have a `dealloc` in his class, sure, that is a problem, but `[sourceValues dealloc];` would be entirely wrong (to restate the obvious).

Comment: @bbum Yeah, of course :) "I'm not using dealloc" is simply not true if you're using Objective C, since it's called automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking the retainCount, something like:

NSLog(@"retain count: %d", [sourceValues retainCount]);

ONLY use for testing/debugging, don't rely on this in an if statement.

Also, you can try iterating over sourceValues and print its contents to NSLog, but I have no idea what's in there.

BEST thing to do is setup a class property as an MSMutableArray with RETAIN, and use synthesize.  The dealloc will take care of the release.

If the above is implemented, you can alloc/init as follows:

```
self.sourceValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

and then add objects directly to self.sourceValues as needed.  No need to worry about releasing, it will be done in dealloc.

Comment: autoreleasing won't work for the set up I'm using. I'm not using dealloc to clear things.

Comment: why not use dealloc?  Don't make things harder for yourself ;)

Comment: `-retainCount` should not be used.  Not even for debugging.

Comment: @tbone you should **never** call `dealloc` directly.  Not. Ever. (In case the joke was lost)

Comment: @bbum when did I ever say "call" dealloc directly?  By "use dealloc" I mean rely on dealloc to do the releases...jeesh ;)

Comment: @everyone: if tbone has defended his side, then revert back his -1 vote.